# Oracle Linux Database Configuration Warning

Tags: database, linux, oracle, configuration, installation

I am trying to install a database for my database admin class.  Our teacher had us install a database from scratch and now we are to load a new database that he created instead of starting from scratch.  The problem I am having is at the end of the database configuration I receive a warning from the database configuration assistant stating the following:

**Enterprise manager configuration failed due to the following error - 
Failed to allocate port(s) in the specified range(s) for the following
process(es): JMS [5540-5559], RMI[5520-5539], Database Control
[5500-5519],EM Agent [3938]|[1830-1849]
refer to the log file at
/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/Lab3/emConfig.log for more details.
You can retry configuring this database with Enterprise Manager later
by manually running /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/bin/emca script.**

I ran the said script and don't know if it completed successfully seeing as I did not 
receive any message saying so.  If you can help I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Well, did you look in the log file?

Comment: Yeah I did but It was hard for me to understand.  Do you know a keyword I am looking for in that log file?  I am a student for this course so I am just learning the admin side of databases.

Comment: Do you have other processes open using one of those ports already?

Comment: @OldProgrammer has a point here. It appears another (EM?) process is already running, preventing you to start another.